# SAS Enterprise Miner split Dataset by binary variable

Tags: sas, enterprise-miner

I am using the SAS Enterprise Miner 13.2.

I have a SAS table as a data source. In this table i have a binary variable D_TYP ( "I" and "P" ) and other categorical variables.

I want to split the data by D_TYP so i got two tables. One with all "I" and the other with "P". The problem i don’t know how.

I have been looking in the taskbar and i tried Filter and Data Partition. I can probably use SAS Code to split the Data but i think there is an other way with the taks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two filter nodes to do the job, with one filtering out `I` and the another filtering out `P`. The resulted data set should only consist of one type of the binary variable. In case you are not familiar with the filter node, click on the option `Class Variable` at properties panel and apply `User specified filter`. You have to manually select the group by clicking on its corresponding `bar`.